# How to Update TextBox on Master Page after first postback?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, postback, pageload

Hello everyone so I am having a bit of a problem and know someone here can help me because I cannot figure this out.

I have a master page that includes a div that contains textboxes for $ and time totals for a client as they select services in the content page.

The problem I am having is that when a service is selected, the first postback does not display the updated totals on the div in master page. Upon second postback the results of the first selection are then displayed.

I understand that this is because the postback is not handled until after page load.  But I do not know how to fix this. I tried to call the master page's method that handles the updating of totals from the init method of the content page, but when I do this, the textboxes of the master page are null.

Here is my code behind for the master page:

```
namespace Teres.App
{
    public partial class App : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        Teres.Controllers.Math M;



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            TextBox1.Text = "customized for: " + HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = "member: " + HttpContext.Current.Session["IsMember"].ToString();
            TextBox3.Text = "membership info: " + HttpContext.Current.Session["MoreInfo"].ToString();

            //need to create dynamic textboxes for service events
            //will call method from Tab class
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                TabMath();
            }


        }

        public void UpdateBar (string service)
        {
            //TextBox TextBox = new TextBox();


        }

        public void TabMath ()
        {
            M = new Teres.Controllers.Math();
            string dollarTotal = Convert.ToString(M.GetDollarTotal());
            TextBox29.Text = "total: $" + dollarTotal;

            string minuteTotal = Convert.ToString(M.GetMinuteTotal());
            TextBox30.Text = "time: " + minuteTotal + " minutes";
        }


    }
}
```

and here is my codebehind for content page

```
namespace Teres.App
{
    public partial class Services : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Teres.Controllers.Services S;
        Teres.Controllers.Math M;

        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




        }


        protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            S = new Teres.Controllers.Services();
            M = new Teres.Controllers.Math();

            if(CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = S.GetHandDescription("manicure");
                TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(S.GetHandTimes("manicure"));
                TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(S.GetHandPrices("manicure"));

                M.UpdateMinuteTotal(S.GetHandTimes("manicure"));
                M.UpdateDollarTotal(S.GetHandPrices("manicure"));

                //Teres.App.App.UpdateBar("manicure");
            }

            else
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                TextBox2.Text = "";
                TextBox3.Text = "";

                M.SubtractMinuteTotal(S.GetHandTimes("manicure"));
                M.SubtractDollarTotal(S.GetHandPrices("manicure"));

                //Teres.App.App.UpdateBar("manicure");
            }
        }
```

How can I update textbox29 and textbox30 right after selection so that postback shows up right away on master page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out just now and thought I would post for the fellow rookies like me looking to solve this problem.

I learned that the prerender stage allows you to update the controls on the page just before it renders, but this stage is after the postback is processed.

```
 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                TabMath();
            }
        }
```

This allowed the total to show the correct version after each postback.

Hope it helps someone else as well.